# install operating system image on sd card mac error

Tags: image, macos, installation, operating-system

I try to install an operating system image on sd card from mac and i got an error.

First I list all my partitions:

```
diskutil list
```

I got:

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MONITOR-IOS             4.0 GB     disk2s1
```

and i run:

```
sudo dd if=bananian-1504.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m && diskutil eject disk2
Password:
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Invalid argument
1811+1 records in
1811+0 records out
1898971136 bytes transferred in 176.389385 secs (10765790 bytes/sec)
```

Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer seems to be that you have specified `of=/dev/rdisk2` when you mean `of=/dev/disk2` - is it really that simple?

Comment: Yep, this a difference between Linux and the BSD derived OS X. Linux requires "of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1M" and BSD/OS X requires "of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m"

Answer (score 1):

While the selected answer is technically "correct" if you goal is to get the `Invalid argument` message to go away. I'd like to point out the using `rdisk` still works in spite of the message and writing to a "raw disk" device is drastically faster than writing to a buffered disk (with is what `/dev/disk2` is).

I still use `rdisk`. And in fact I believe that messaging to be wrong and actually triggered by another cause. I'll not go into that until I can prove it.